# Is there a way to set an vertical ruler in VSCode for Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I look for a way to set a vertical ruler in the Jupyter extension of VSCode similar to editor.rulers in the text editor.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The latest VSCode notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Native-Notebook-Support-in-VS-Code) supports ruler (see below).

[image]

It uses the same ruler setting in `editor.rulers`. In fact, the code cell appears no different from a regular text editor. For instance all the keybindings defined in text editor also works in a code cell, which was not the case in the previous version.